# Unexplainable line in Blender Sculpt

Tags: sculpting

I may have enabled an option by mistake. When I try to sculpt, a line appears that slows my sculpt, how do I disable it ?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disable **Smooth Stroke** in the Stroke **section**.

[image: smooth stroke]

In Blender 2.8x this has been renamed to *Stabilize Stroke*.

[image: Stabilize stroke]